# How to: wpf datagrid totally programmatical, including binding to observablecollection

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection, programmatically-created

I have to perform the entire thing in code, and am at loss after spending two says in StackOverflow and dear uncle google.

I have a class `TestData:InotifyPropertyChanged` which includes a `string` "Name", another `string` "Specifics" and an `bool array` "checks". This class is used to build a static `Observablecollection` "testData" (lowercase).

I'd like to create by code a `datagrid`, not let it make automatic columns, and present these columns:

1. `DataGridTextColumn` with "Name", non-editable.
2. `DataGridTextColumn` with "Specifics", editable (and presenting a default value "-").
3. Three `DataGridCheckBoxColum`s with the "checks" data.

The strucutre is set-up properly, and displays the required headers and the placeholders for the data. There's a button which adds new records to "testData", and additional rows are indeed added to the datagrid, but sadly these are empty.

I need this to be two-way, obviously.

I can't manage to display the values I have set in the declaration of the "testData" for "specifics" and "checks".

In addition, I keep receiving an error saying that "two way binding requires Path or x:path". It's frustrating...

Here's what I tried:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMainDataGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```

and

```
dgMainDataGrid.ItemsSource = testData;

DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
col1.Header = "col1Header";
col1.IsReadOnly = true;
col1.Binding = new Binding("Name");

DataGridTextColumn col2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
col2.Header = "col2Header";
col2.IsReadOnly = false;
col2.Binding = new Binding("Specifics");

DataGridCheckBoxColumn col3 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
col3.Header = "col3Header";
col3.IsReadOnly = false;
col3.Binding = new Binding("checks[0]");


DataGridCheckBoxColumn col4 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
col4.Header = "col3Header";
col4.IsReadOnly = false;
col4.Binding = new Binding("checks[1]");

DataGridCheckBoxColumn col5 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
col5.Header = "col3Header";
col5.IsReadOnly = false;
col5.Binding = new Binding("checks[2]");
```

and class

```
public class TestData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public string Name;
public string Specifics;
public bool[] checks;
}
```

Thanks, guys.

Comment: Please have a look, it might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645849/wpf-dynamic-columns-and-values-for-datagrid/31646240#31646240

Comment: How does your TestData class look like?

Comment: OOPS! These are not properties... My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Clemens asked how my class looks, I saw these were not properties. Just sprinkle some {get; set;} over the fields.